# Затемнение фона по времени

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Скажите как реализовать затемнение фона по времени , т.е к примеру через 4сек должен фон из картинки стать темнее или цветной фон должен стать чёрно-белым ?

Comment: если решено уже - какой смысл что то уточнять ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример перехода цветного изображения в черно-белое на css

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.block {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.block-pict {
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  background: url('http://i3.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article3433397.ece/ALTERNATES/s1200/Leicester-City-fans-display-a-celebratory-banner.jpg') no-repeat center top;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-animation: anim 4s forwards;
  animation: anim 4s forwards;
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  }
  50% {
    filter: grayscale(50%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(50%);
  }
  100% {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block-pict"></div>
</div>
```